# To give a button a tag dynamically/android

Tags: android, listview, button

I am writing an Android programm. My program has a customized ListView. 
Now each line of the list contains a TextField and a Button. 
I want the Textfield to react when I press the Button.

This is simple when hardcoded, but how do I do this dynamically?

Seems to me, for this I ought to be able to assign a tag to each button and textfield dynamically, so that each button has the same tag as the textfield next to it.

EDIT:
I do not think it will help any, but here what I have tried so far, first the xml files:

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context="com.example.pris.ViewActivity"
  tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:text="@string/myText" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/textfield"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tex"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/suchen"
        android:layout_below="@id/tex"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textfield"
        android:onClick="addToList"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but2"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Liste löschen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/but"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="removeList" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/but2"></ListView>
```

and:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Itemname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:onClick="rem"
    />
```

As for the javacode:

```
                      package com.example.pris;


//HauptView
public class ViewActivity extends ListActivity {


//Wirkstoffliste. Nötig für den Adapter fürs Autocomplete
private static final String[] MEDICATIONS = {"Indometacin", "Acemetacin", "Ketoprofen", "Phenylbutazon",
        "Piroxicam", "Meloxicam", "Etoricoxib", "Pethidin", "Chinidin", "Flecainid", "Sotalol", "Digoxin",
        "Nitrofurantoin", "Hydroxyzin", "Clemastin", "Dimetinden", "Chlorphenamin"
};
//Adapter für die ExpandableListView
private ArrayAdapter adap;

//Textfeld, in das der User seine Anfrage eingibt
private AutoCompleteTextView edit;
//der aktuelle Context
final Context con = this;

public int selectedItem = -1;

protected Object mActionMode;


private String chosen;

private List<String> meds = new ArrayList();



//Das passiert beim Betätigen des Searchbuttons:
//Es wird ein Asynctask erstellt, der abfragt, ob der Wirkstoff in der Liste vorkommt und dann entsprechend die Anzeige modelliert.
//Danach wird das Textfeld wieder auf Null gesetzt.
public void addToList(View view) {

    System.out.println(view);

    String str = "";
    boolean here = false;
    str = edit.getText().toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < MEDICATIONS.length; i++)
        if (MEDICATIONS[i].equals(str)) {

            here = true;
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < meds.size(); j++) {
                if (meds.get(j).equals(str)) {
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!duplicate) {

             //   adap.add(str);
                meds.add(str);
                adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                View v =  this.getListView();
                System.out.println(v);


            break;

        }
    if (!here){
        Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, "Bitte geben Sie einen anderen Wirkstoff ein", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    edit.setText(null);
}}


public void rem(View view){
}


//Entfernt bei Anklicken von "Liste löschen" die gesamte Liste
public void removeList(View view) {
    meds.clear();
    adap.clear();
    adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
//OnCreate. Die View wird ans xml gebunden und weitere Methoden ausgelöst.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, R.layout.mylist,
            R.id.Itemname, meds);
   this.setListAdapter(adap);
     //  adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
    if (getIntent().getExtras()!= null){
        System.out.println("not null");
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int i;
        String str;

    for (i = 0; i< bundle.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(bundle);
        System.out.println(bundle.keySet());
        str = bundle.getString(String.valueOf(i));
        meds.add(str);
        adap.add(str);

    }

   /* if (i==0){
        meds.clear();
        adap.clear();
    }

    */}

    else
    {System.out.println("  null");}
    setAutocomplete();
    //setExpandList();


}

}
```

As you can see, I have a Listview with dynamically generated buttons - now How do I address one of them, say the fourth or fifth or 16th?

There must be some possibility, but it is damn hard to find

Comment: post what you have already tried please

Comment: I am still puzzling over the problem of HOW to access a listviews component. I can of course post my xml files and also my viewactivity, but I have not so far TRIED to access a button within the listview, if I knew how to do that I would not ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example i took from this [tutorial](http://blog.mettletech.co/wp/blog/settag-and-gettag-on-listview/).
Look at the method known as

> getView()

in the adapter.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;
MyThumbnaildapter thadapter=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_fruit);
String[] name=new String[]{"fruit_logo1","fruit_logo2","fruit_logo3","fruit_logo4","fruit_logo5","fruit_logo6","fruit_logo7","fruit_logo8","fruit_logo9","fruit_logo10","fruit_logo11","fruit_logo12"};
String[] pic=new String[]{"Apple","Banana","Papaya","Coconut","Pineapple","Grapes","Guava","Tomato","Watermelon","Lime","Orange","Mango"};
thadapter=new MyThumbnaildapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list,pic,name);
listView.setAdapter(thadapter);
thadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] ar;
private String[] pic;
public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] ar,String[] pic) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, ar);
this.ar=ar;
this.pic=pic;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = convertView;
if(view==null)
{
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_hint);
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
view.setTag(new Holder(imageView,textView));

}

Holder h = (Holder) view.getTag();
h.textView.setText(ar[position]);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(pic[position], "drawable", getPackageName());
h.imageView.setImageResource(resID);
return view;
}
}
private class Holder{
public final ImageView imageView;
public final TextView textView;
private Holder(ImageView imageView,TextView textView) {
this.imageView = imageView;
this.textView = textView;
}
}
}
```